# Only in Docker container: ec_key_simple_check_key:invalid private key

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, openssl, bouncycastle

I use BouncyCastle.Crypto 1.8.5.0 to create a SecurityKey for authenticating against Apple's APNS HTTP/2 endpoint. It works just fine when debugging on MacOS Mojave, but when I deploy in a Docker container, I get the following exception:

```
Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1010207B:elliptic curve routines:ec_key_simple_check_key:invalid private key
    at System.Security.Cryptography.ECOpenSsl.ImportParameters(ECParameters parameters)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create(ECParameters parameters)
```

After reading [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27130#issuecomment-504179108) I tried to force using OpenSSL 1.1 by setting env variable CLR_OPENSSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.1 and making sure the latest openssl is installed in the Dockerfile, but no fix.

Code which reads private key file and initializes SecurityKey:

```
using (var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText (PathToApnsKeyFile)) {
    var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader (reader).ReadObject ();
    var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded ();
    var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded ();
    var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned ();
    // Convert the BouncyCastle key to a Native Key.
    var msEcp = new ECParameters { Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256, Q = { X = x, Y = y }, D = d };
    jwtPrivateKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey (ECDsa.Create (msEcp));
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out -r linux-x64

# build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS runtime
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install openssl
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "helloapple.dll"]
```

**UPDATE**

My MacOS appears to be using LibreSSL 2.6.5. The openssl version being pulled by apt-get is 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7.

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  The version of Net has to be able to support the Encryption mode.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1, but like I said, the code works perfectly fine on MacOS. So the problem would rather be in the native part

Comment: What version Open SSL are you using?  The error is the version of OpenSSL not supporting the encryption mode or the parameters set wrong.  Keys can have padding or no padding the the padding mode may be wrong.

Comment: The Dockerfile makes sure to get the latest version of openssl, as you can see. I'm not sure which exact version was downloaded, but it did say 1.1-something

Comment: I re-ran docker build with empty cache and it appears to download the following openssl version: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7

Comment: I'm not an expert in all these versions.  I think the encryption is in the ubuntu kernel.  So the kernel need to support the mode and docker need to support the ubuntu.  For example if you upgrade ubuntu to 14.04 you need to use the equivalent docker 18.06.2.

Comment: See if following helps : https://cryptsus.com/blog/how-to-secure-your-ssh-server-with-public-key-elliptic-curve-ed25519-crypto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Turns out the problem is in the implementation of the curve parameters, which differs between platforms. The above code works on Windows and Mac, but apparently not on Linux. The correct calculation is:

```
var q = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.Multiply (ecPrivateKeyParameters.D).Normalize ();
var x = q.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded ();
var y = q.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded ();
var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned ();
// Convert the BouncyCastle key to a Native Key.
var msEcp = new ECParameters { Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256, Q = { X = x, Y = y }, D = d };
```

Solution was found in the following comment on github:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2037#issuecomment-436340605